# How to insert a View inside other View as the last row of the parent View?

Tags: views

I need  to insert a View inside other View as the last row of the parent View.

**I know I can create a Attachtment but this will be shown before or after the rows of the parent view. I need it to be inserted as the last row of the parent view**

Let's say the parent view lists "basic pages" nodes and the inserted view lists "articles" nodes.

Then the results of what I need would be: 6 rows: the first five rows will be "basic pages" and the last one will an "article".

Is there any way to get this?

Answer (score 1):

Use [views_field_view](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_field_view) module. 
This module help you to embed a view as a field in a view.

Comment: This module add a view field in every row of the view. I need the inserted view to be the last row of the view.

Comment: You can add your child view in view footer as well.

Comment: I need it as a row not in the footer or header

Comment: @chefnelone did you try the module? It does add the view as a row.

Answer (score 1):

Below are the modules. I hope any of these help you to solve this :

1. [Node Embed](https://www.drupal.org/project/node_embed)

> Node Embed provides an input filter for CKEditor integration allowing
>   a content editor the ability to embed the rendering of nodes within
>   the body/fields of another node. This uses a View to allow for the
>   browsing/preview/selection of a node to embed and provides a set of
>   template suggestions that allow for the detailed control of node
>   rendering when in embedded mode.

2. [Views Field View](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_field_view)

> This module allows you to embed a view as a field in a view. A new
>   field handler is made available, so this can also be used in area
>   (header/footer/empty) handlers as well as rows.
>
> This view handler can accept arguments from fields of the parent view
>   using tokens and pass them into the child view for each row. Raw or
>   rendered token values can be used, as well as static values.

[Inserting Views](https://www.drupal.org/node/48816) - Read the content & comments. I hope this may help.

Comment: I just tried the Views Field View. This module add a view field in every row of the view. I need the inserted view to be insert just one time and as the last row of the view.

Comment: Have you try Node Embed module. Try to Read the Inserting Views content. I hope you may got some help from there.

Comment: I tried it, but I see no integration at all within views. It seems to work inside nodes instead.

Answer (score 0):

in your view settings, middle column add in footer a  Global: View (Views field view). Embed a views_field_view field in an area. This can also accept argument tokens. pick the view you desire to add, done.